# ARMv6 build for Gingerbread in AOSP

Tags: android, arm, porting, android-source, cyanogenmod

I am trying to port gingerbread to a development board with an ARM11 MPcore processor with ARMv6k architecture. I have added a device to the AOSP source, and my problem is that when I set 'TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT' to armv6k, armv6 or armv6-vfp, I get an error saying that it is unknown when I run lunch.

```
build/core/combo/TARGET_linux-arm.mk:39: *** Unknown ARM architecture version: armv6-vfp.  Stop.
```

Is armv6 supported in AOSP, and if so where could I find the possible TARGET_ARCH_VARIANTs? I have been looking around and it seems that CyanogenMod may provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`armv6` build settings are extra patches from [CodeAurora](http://www.codeaurora.org) (Qualcomm) and they are absent in AOSP. If you are working on a QC platform better get the Android source from CodeAurora. If you are working on a non QC platform, you can still use their patches around armv6. However that might turn out to be an exhausting job with scattered patches in different gits.

Comment: I've found that the directory "build/core/combo/arch/arm" has the makefiles for all allowed architectures. Do you think that using 'armv5te' should be backwards compatible and work? How important is this setting overall? You probably have not heard of the chip I am porting to (quatro5300).

Comment: @Methos armv5te is the way to go if you have an armv6 device on AOSP.